# Crystal report Multi Select parameter Issue

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report. Data source is  Stored procedure and a Command for displaying (printing )parameters.

Crystal report is an excel extract from CA Clarity. when i am passing correct parameters i.e if parameter has data matching i get the data as well as parameters are printed as desired.

But in wrong scenario for UN-matching parameters,the parameters prints nothing.
out of all the parameters i have one multiple select parameter which is a report level.

Below is my parameters command

```
SELECT

NVL(NAME,'ALL') NAME FROM 

(
SELECT LISTAGG(NAME,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY NAME) AS NAME
FROM
(
select V.NAME from cmn_lookups_v V where lookup_type='XYZ' and language_code= 'en' and
v.lookup_code in {?PARAM_INV_TYPE})
)
```

Comment: Can you explain more? What is correct parameter and wrong parameter

Comment: correct parameter is for getting data. I mean the parameter which is passed and data is found.Wronng Parameter is for which we wont get any data.

Comment: when there is no data to display then there wont be anything printed on report.... what are your looking for?

Comment: i'm printing parameter value,from the above query i m printing name column in my report header. When there is no data matching for the value passed for eg .A is passed then i will get no records but value A should be printed on my header. But it doesn't print. This is the isssue.

Comment: is the parameter static or dynamic? normally the value should print... may be dynamic nature of parameter is the issue.

Comment: Parameter is static, at any point of time it will have 2 values. 
for null we are getting all the records.
I have used the below formula in record selection 

(
IF {?PARAM_INV_TYPE}=" " THEN 1=1 
ELSE 

{?PARAM_INV_TYPE}={Z_stored_procedure.column_name}
)

Is this causing the issue??